# Velocity and Distance; Functions of Time

Tags: functions, physics

$s(t)$ = distance a particle travels from time $0$ to $t$. If in this case, the distance $s$ is only the function of time then its necessary that the *velocity* should be constant. Likewise, $v(t)$ = velocity of a particle at time $t$, if in this case *velocity* is only the function of *time* then the *distance* traveled should be constant. Am I right?

Comment: What  is the purpose of adding this?

Comment: @exploringnet I just wanted to confirm it.. Am I right?

Comment: You are wrong. What makes you think like that?